# Onvif PTZ Control + RTSP Support using custom Mobile App

Tags: camera, rtsp, ip-camera, onvif

i wanna know and determine which IP cameras support PTZ control & RTSP using onvif to make custom mobile controlling the IP camera.

and which types should i buy T or S?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the two, since they are both related to streaming. Let's say that Profile-T compliant cameras are newer and have more functionalities. For example, you cannot have H.265 in Profile-S compliant cameras (but beware the not all the Profile-T compliant cameras have it).

In order to have an idea about the differences, you can check the [ONVIF Profile Feature Overview](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ONVIF_Profile_Feature_overview_v2-3.pdf).

Comment: as you could have seen from the profile feature overview, S and T are the same for PTZ